# How to use Authentication for user login in Lumen? Why do I see "Unauthorized" upon launch?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, lumen

I have a login page (username/password inputs) that doesn't load/show. Instead, when launching the app, all that shows is "Unauthorized".

This is from a command in `Authenticate.php` that I have included further below.

My `routes.php`:

```
$app->get('/', 'PageController@index');

$app->group(['middleware' => 'middleware.auth'], function ($app) {
    $app->post('/', ['uses' => 'AuthenticationController@login']);
});
```

My `PageController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function index() {

        return view('login');
    }
}
```

My `AuthenticationController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;
class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email','password']);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return'logged in';
        } else {
            return 'not logged in';
        }
    }
}
```

Here's `Authenticate.php` located in 'app\Http\Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

There might be a better way to go about what I'm trying to do, so if there is, please demonstrate to me what that is.

But why am I seeing the `Unauthorized` when my app loads? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're checking whether a user is authenticated before the `AuthenticationController@login` method can be called. You need to remove the middleware auth from the post / route, as essentially what is happening is;

- Homepage (`$app->get('/'...`) opens fine because there is no auth middleware defined for this route
- When you post the login form, Lumen is told that only authenticated users can access that page because of the middleware.auth defined against your `POST /` route.

This should work:
`routes.php`

```
$app->get('/', 'PageController@index');
$app->post('/', ['uses' => 'AuthenticationController@login']);


$app->group(['middleware' => 'middleware.auth'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('/user/dashboard', ['uses' => 'Controller@method']);
});
```

With that, any one can see and submit your login page, but only logged in users can access the URL `/user/dashboard`A. The rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: I updated to your code. Looks like I have a problem with the the Auth attempt. Here's the error I'm getting: `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard' does not have a method 'attempt'`