# How to display particular time format in PHP's Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, time, lumen

In my view, I have this code:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $t) {
    <p> {{ $t->updated_at }} </p>
@endforeach
```

Which ultimately produces:

```
2016-08-18 01:23:45
...
```

Is there anyway to do something to the effect of:

```
{{ $note->updated_at("l, h:i A") }}
```

So that what shows is: `Thursday, 01:23 AM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the date/datetime properties in Eloquent are converted to [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs) object, so you can do it like this,

```
{{ $note->updated_at->format("l, h:i A") }}
```

Comment: Yes! This worked great. Is there anyway you could help with another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022337/lumen-how-to-use-authentication-properly-for-user-login-why-do-i-see-unauthor  (link changed)